# Controlling bounding boxes of a \rotatebox

Tags: boxes, rotating

I tried defining a nicer \emptyset using the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphics}

\renewcommand{\emptyset}{
    \makebox[1em][c]{
        \scalebox{1.1}{
            \rotatebox[origin=c]{21}{$\varnothing$}
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

    \[
        X\neq\emptyset\neq Y
    \]

\end{document}
```

This produces nice-looking results, but when I use a text selecting tool in the pdf, I get a rotated bounding box like this:

[image]

Is there a way to edit this meta information in the macro?

Comment: I don't think so, the adobe reader detects the rotation and shows it.